# How can I have two web roots on one server, so I can point two domains to two different roots?

Tags: domain-name-system, nginx, domain, ip, vps

I usually ask my n00b questions on Stack Exchange, but now I'm setting up a VPS and have a question. My usual site.com points to my VPS's IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. Now I have a different domain, and I'd like to point that to another location, say xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/myname. However, when I try to add that as an "A" record in the DNS settings it won't let me.

FYI I'm using chicagovps.net with ubuntu 11.10 and Nginx.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to do a little research before asking questions (Google: "Name based virtual hosting"). You also need to ask a more specific question if you want answers out of Server Fault -- "It won't let me" isn't an error message or anything else we can troubleshoot. [See here for some tips](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't do that in the DNS, you do it in the web server. It's called "name-based virtual hosting". The `A` record only points to the IP address.